# Update a column of dates in a data frame

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

I got a data frame liks so:

```
df
Name | Date
A      2015-11-01
A      2015-11-02
B      2015-11-01
```

My dataset is quite large so how is the correct way to update the Date column with say 7 days to get:

```
df
Name | Date
A      2015-11-08
A      2015-11-09
B      2015-11-08
```

What is the correct way to deal with this in regards to vectorization? I kow that by using "+" on date objects one can add n days, but how can I apply this for each element in df$Date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest and nicest way is using '+' to the column as follows:

```
df$Date <- df$Date + 7 # This will add 7 days to all entries
```